# Cannot add snappy-dev/tools ppa repository

Tags: software-installation, repository, error-handling, deepin, snap

I am using Deepin Linux 15.4.1 and I want to install the package snapcraft (to do that I need the "title's repository"), when I try to add the snappy-dev/tools repository with the command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:snappy-dev/tools
```

but I get the error:

```
 Official PPA for the Snappy related tools.
  More info: https://launchpad.net/~snappy-dev/+archive/ubuntu/tools
 Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

 gpg: keybox '/tmp/tmp4dbu3qkt/pubring.gpg' created
 gpg: /tmp/tmp4dbu3qkt/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
 gpg: key F1831DDAFC42E99D: public key "Launchpad PPA for Snappy Developers" imported
 gpg: Total number processed: 1
 gpg:               imported: 1
 gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
```

And when I try to add the repository by the second time I get:

Official PPA for the Snappy related tools.
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~snappy-dev/+archive/ubuntu/tools
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

```
gpg: keybox '/tmp/tmphwxyr_qo/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: /tmp/tmphwxyr_qo/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key F1831DDAFC42E99D: public key "Launchpad PPA for Snappy Developers" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 862, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 688, in addkey_func
    func(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 386, in add_key
    return apsk.add_ppa_signing_key()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 273, in add_ppa_signing_key
    cleanup(tmp_keyring_dir)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 234, in cleanup
    shutil.rmtree(tmp_keyring_dir)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/shutil.py", line 480, in rmtree
    _rmtree_safe_fd(fd, path, onerror)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/shutil.py", line 438, in _rmtree_safe_fd
    onerror(os.unlink, fullname, sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/shutil.py", line 436, in _rmtree_safe_fd
    os.unlink(name, dir_fd=topfd)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado: 'S.gpg-agent.extra'
```

I read lots of suggestions in the forums about this stuff but I didn't find any posts with the same error as mine.
I tried adding others repositories related to snap but I get the same error as I said in this post; how can I resolve this?

Comment: Not sure why you're getting that error, but that PPA is defunct and no longer updated anyway (it's mostly from the pre-xenial days). Snapcraft is in the Ubuntu archives these days, which doesn't really help you much. If you can install snapd on Deepin, you can try installing the Snapcraft snap: `sudo snap install --candidate snapcraft`.

Comment: This command you said showed me a message telling me to use sudo snap install --candidate --classic snapcraft instead, anyway just for the ones who see this post and fix that stuff in one command :P - Btw it worked, thx

Comment: Agh, and of course I can't edit. Sorry Rodrigo, thanks for the response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [answer from the comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/396910/cannot-add-snappy-dev-tools-ppa-repository#comment708719_396910):

```
snap install --candidate --classic snapcraft
```

Comment: This does not help if you don't have `snap` installed though.